# Video Blocker for Safari

Tags: safari, youtube, safari-extensions, adblock

I was using chrome for a long time and video blocker always helped me in game release date. 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/video-blocker/jknkjnpcbbgcbdbaampbjlhkcghmgfhk

I'm looking similar extension for safari. Is there something like that or maybe you have some adblock/uBlock origin rules for that?